# Proper select and join query with multiple entry from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two table, tblCar(left) and tblReserve(right)
[image]

Now I just want to select all from tblCar where (get the nearest date to current date and if the nearest date and its number of day is > 3 it will be viewed and if the itemId is not found in the tblReserve it will be viewed also).

the output should be

[image]

How can I put conditions in linq that will check every date and if the date passed the condition the item will be viewed?

I already know how to join them but not with condition where you check every date.

Comment: be clear of what are you asking. Do you wish to have the query as LINQ? or SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give your expected result.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM tblCar tc
 LEFT JOIN tblReserve tr ON tc.itemID = tr.itemID
 WHERE tr.itemID IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(tr.date, CURDATE()) > 3
 ORDER BY tc.itemID
```

Comment: did OP asked for SQL query?

Comment: No, But wishing condition. & so i give a query.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use interval from mysql to get your result

```
SELECT *
 FROM tblCar Car
 LEFT JOIN tblReserve Res ON Res.itemID = Car.itemID
 WHERE Res.itemID IS NULL OR Res.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```